# Janusgraph Gremlin: How to find if a vertex has at least 1 relationship/edge to a thousands of vertex with specific property

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Let say I have this sample data

```
Vertex[type: Person, name: Foo] ---hasPet---> Vertex[type: Dog, name: Dog1]
Vertex[type: Person, name: Bar] ---hasPet---> Vertex[type: Cat, name: Cat1]
Vertex[type: Person, name: Bazz] ---hasPet---> Vertex[type: Dog, name: Dog2]
Vertex[type: Person, name: Bazz] ---hasPet---> Vertex[type: Dog, name: Dog3]
```

Then I wanted to find any Person-type vertex who has at least has pet which is a dog.

How could find all those Person-type vertices without traversing all the non-person type vertices?

I tried this query, but still it is traversing all pets of `Bazz`, I wanted to stop the traversal as soon as I found any matches since `Bazz` might have thousand other pets.

My query:

```
g.traversal().V().has("type", "Person").repeat(out("hasPet").simplePath()).until(has("type", "Dog")).simplePath().in().valueMap("name")
```

And this is the result:

```
[Foo]
[Bazz]
[Bazz]
```

What I like is:

```
[Foo]
[Bazz]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `dedup` step to remove any duplicate results:

```
g.V().has('type', 'Person').
  repeat(out('hasPet').simplePath()).
  until(has('type', 'Dog')).simplePath().in().
  valueMap('name').dedup()
```

I'm not sure why you don't use different labels for your vertices, and at least in your sample data the `repeat` step and the `in` are redundant. instead, you can do a much simpler query:

```
g.V().has('type', 'Person').
  where(out('hasPet').has('type', 'Dog')).
  values('name').dedup()
```

example: https://gremlify.com/m33b6dsxnim

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I wrote this query for illustration. What I wanted to know actually is if there is a way to avoid 'out()' to traverse all outer vertices and stop on the first match because outer vertices could reach up to hundred thousands and will impact performance.